# How can I use machine learning to find the aspect ratio of particles in a simulation?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a gravitational model where particles (n ~ 1000) are being pulled by a massive blackhole. The particles can be seen to get stretched due to this. I want to measure this aspect ratio (Length : Width) vs time plot.

An example of this stretching can be seen in this clipping (different colours show different times, so this shows evolution of the particles):[image]

I tried doing this in a different way by considering the velocity vector and rotating one of the position axis to this and measuring the length and width that way. But at some point the center of mass velocity vector doesn’t point (or align) towards the stretching.

Is there a way I can do this using other algorithms in computational geometry/machine learning?

Comment: You can use standard algorithms to compute the *convex hull* of your pixel cloud, then calculate the largest and the smallest diameter and take the ratio of the two. Both steps are standard computational geometry, no ML required.

Comment: You might want to look through [the computational-geometry tag on Computer Graphics.SE](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry), or [at CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry). Once you have decided which site is more appropriate, flag this question for moderator attention and request migration.

Comment: What do you mean by Length : Width? How do you define them for arbitrary 2D particle agglomerates in 2D space, and how physically meaningful is that definition?

Comment: I would begin by characterizing these clouds with low-order moments (it appears first and second moments would work pretty well) and using physical theory to formulate models of the evolution of those moments over time.  That would give you some analytical traction and access to standard, powerful statistical methods of solution (like vector time series analysis).  Having some expertise in computational geometry, I nevertheless see no need to apply any of its special tools for this problem.